# How to split a string into array of letters in MongoDB aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I want to split a string into array of letters just like we do in javascript,
Eg,

```
let x = "String";
x.split('') // ['S', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

But, if I do the same using $split in aggregation pipeline, like below,

```
{
 $project:{
 _id:"$_id._id",
 name:"$_id.name",
 array_field:{ $split: ["$_id.name", ""] }
 }
}
```

its throwing me error like this,

```
{
    "message" : "PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $split requires a non-empty separator",
    "ok" : 0,
    "code" : 40087,
    "codeName" : "Location40087",
    "name" : "MongoError"
}
```

can anyone help me out with this problem. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...$split requires a non-empty separator

That is the expected error when you split a string (using `$split` aggregate operator) with a `""` (string with zero length) as a *delimiter*.

You can try this approach to get the desired result (this splits the string field `str: "string"` to an array field `arr: [ "s", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g" ]`):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          arr: {
              $function: {
                  body: function(s) {
                               return s.split('');
                  },
                  args: [ "$str" ],
                  lang: "js"
              }
          }
      }
  }
])
```

Note that the usage of `$function` requires MongoDB v4.4.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you combined [$substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) with [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/), we will iterate over the length of the string and use `$substr` to select the character at index `i`, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "newField": {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $range: [
              0,
              {
                "$strLenCP": "$key"
              }
            ]
          },
          in: {
            "$substr": [
              "$key",
              "$$this",
              1
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MzUEQyAyJW9)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That's actually the only that works (I've searched and tried a lot including the accepted answer above which didn't work for me).

The only point I'd like to mention - if we're using $strLenCP, I'd go with $substrCP instead of $substr.